# How to align text in a Visio text block

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

How do you align the text within a MS Visio text block, to the top/bottom/left/right? I am soooo confused, and after a few minutes I give in - thoughts?

[image]

note: by "it" in the picture above I am referencing the text within the Text Block, my apologies! :)

Answer (score 3):

On the Home tab -> Paragraph section
there are 3 options for horizontal and 3 options for vertical text alighnment.
You can do the same thing with the right-click menu -> Format -> Text
which brings up the Text dialog where, on the Paragragh tab, you can select the vertical alignment.